# How can I change NLog rule target during runtime?

Tags: .net, nlog

I have the original configuration:

```
<rules>
    <logger name="Logger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="FileLog,syslog" />
</rules>
```

It will print to file as well as send to server.

I expect to change target during runtime, sometimes to FileLog, sometimes to syslog and sometimes to both.
Is there a programmable way?

Comment: I would like to write methods like `DisableAllSyslogTargets` `EnableAllTargets` `EnableOnlySyslogTargets`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two options: enabled autoreload of the config (`<nlog autoreload="true"`) and change the config file.

Or programmatically:

#### Edit `<logger>`

```cs
// remove syslog from first rule
var config = LogManager.Configuration;
config.LoggingRules[0].Targets.RemoveAt(1); 
LogManager.Configuration = config; // Apply new config
```

#### Edit `<logger>` with more rules

If you have more rules, then using the rule index is a bit cumbersome. For this case, NLog added a `ruleName` option - Introduced in NLog 4.6.4.

```xml
<rules>
    <logger name="Logger" rulename="rule1" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="FileLog" />
    <logger name="Logger" rulename="rule2" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="Syslog" />
</rules>
```

You can now edit the `<logger>` with `FindRuleByName` and `RemoveRuleByName`

e.g.

```cs
var config = LogManager.Configuration;
config.FindRuleByName("rule2").EnableLoggingForLevel(LogLevel.Debug); //enable level debug
config.RemoveRuleByName("rule1"); // Remove rule

LogManager.Configuration = config; // Apply new config
```

Note, when the "rule name" isn't unique, the first rule is used with that name.

### Edit targets

#### With Layout

The question above talks about "change target during runtime", which isn't fully what is described above because that is about log rules.

You could also edit targets and that easier.

If a target has a Layoutable value (visible in the docs with `Layout`), you could use layout renderers, e.g. context classes like [${gdc}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer) (global context)

e.g. The [console target definition](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Console-target):

```xml
 <target xsi:type="Console"
          name="String"
          layout="Layout"
          ... 
          encoding="Encoding"
          ...
```

Has a layoutable layout

So we could do:

```xml
<target name="target1" xsi:type="Console"  layout="${gdc:myLayout}"/>
```

and in code

```cs
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("MyLayout", "${message} ${exception");
```

#### Without layout

If it isn't layoutable, e.g. the "encoding" in the console target, you could do:

```cs
var config = LogManager.Configuration;
config.FindTargetByName<ConsoleTarget>("target1").Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
LogManager.Configuration = config; // Apply new config
```

Update: extended with more examples, variations and updated to latest recommendations.

Comment: Why 0? Why 1? What if the configuration file has some normal level of complexity (multiple targets, multiple rules per target)?

Comment: In this question there is only one rule. Nowadays there's an easier way when having multiple rules. Will update the answer soon.

Comment: @4myle updated. Let me know if this will answer your questions :)